# jquery to animate background on hover

Tags: jquery, css

am not a pro in jquery but i have been searching and doing somecode to do the following

i need a hover animation to replace some images on hover effect (asd.png to asd-hover.png),
here is what i wrote but still need something to replace these 2 methods (replace, match)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var effect = $('a.dribble')
    effect.mouseover(function(){
        var bg = effect.attr('src').match('/[^\.]+/') + '-hover.png';
        $(this).stop().animate({
            background: bg ,
            duration:500
        })  
        console.log('in')       
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
         var bg = effect.attr('src').replace("-hover.png", ".png");
        $(this).stop().animate({
            background: bg + '-hover.png',
            duration:500
        })
        console.log('out')  
    })
});
```

Any help  ?!?!?

Comment: no, no, just a cool fading between 2 images

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YeydX/

Answer (score 1):

Animations are for numerical values only. Give JQuery two background images (strings) and it won't be able to do anything with them. You're better off having two elements with their own background image, placing one over the other with CSS position—and fading the top one in and out.

Comment: @McCloud86 It's possible also with jQuery, but only as texelate suggests. If you want a background transition, you need two background images. Then you can adjust their opacity: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/lalatino/ff7zs/) Anyway you're right, it's much easier by using css3.